# Gauss Jacobi method in C

Tags: c++, c, math

The code on Gauss-Jacobi method in Applied maths doesn't execute successfully on compilation although there are no errors:

```
void main(){
    int a[3][4], i, j, k;
    float x,y,z;
    printf("Enter coeff of 3 equations and RHS :");
    for(i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    printf("\nEQUATION %d",i);
    for(j = 1; j <= 4; j++){
    scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    x = (a[1][4])/(a[1][1]);
    y = (a[2][4])/(a[2][2]);
    z = (a[3][4])/(a[3][3]);
    printf("\nx0=%d y0=%d and z0=%d", x, y, z);
    printf("\nEnter no. of iterations:");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    i=0;
  while(i < k){
    i++;
    x = a[1][4]-(a[1][2]*y)-(a[1][3]*z);
    y = a[2][4]-(a[2][3]*z)-(a[2][1]*x);
    z = a[3][4]-(a[3][2]*y)-(a[3][1]*x);
    printf("\n after %d itr,\n x=%f\ny=%f\n z=%f", i, x, y, z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Missing input values and expected results.

Comment: `void main` is invalid. `main` should return `int`.

Comment: No clue what Gauss-Jacobi is, but I'm going to go ahead and assume the problem is that integer division returns an integer. E.g., `3/4` == 0, because integers aren't floating point numbers. However, if you did `((float)3)/4` you'll get a float back.

Comment: Why do maths people always write such eye-hurting code? And not seem to know that they are doing it?

Comment: Why is this tagged `c++`?

Comment: What's up with the random indentation?

Comment: @NeilButterworth ..probably because it looks nice to a mathematician.  OK, it's unreadable and undebuggable, which is why it gets posted here~;(

Comment: Compilation errors are the programmer's concern; they aren't good questions for SO.  Mathematicians don't have to write bad code, any more than programmers have to be terrible at math.  Gauss Jacobi is not the best way to solve linear algebra problems.  I'd recommend LU decomposition.  The choice of Gauss Jacobi suggests someone who is not informed about math or numerical methods.

Answer (score 1):

The problem your code are the things like these:  `x = (a[1][4])/(a[1][1]);`. Here `x` is float var and calculation you are doing in that are both int values. As @PhilM stated, `3/4 == 0`, because integers aren't floating point numbers. To fix this, you should consider doing casting. It will fix your problem.

How to cast example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {

   int sum = 17, count = 5;
   double mean;

   mean = (double) sum / count;
   printf("Value of mean : %f\n", mean );

}
```

Casting is simple, you just put `(the type of var)` in front of the variable. In your case, `(float)(a[1][4])/ (float)(a[1][1]);`.